# How to find p99 execution time for AWS Lambda Functions Dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to improve my user experience by providing average load times based on lambda function execution time. To do this I setup a CloudWatch dashboard which pulls the p99 execution time for each of my endpoints. Unfortunately, I am at a loss on how to actually pull this data.

Using the AWS SDK, I found that the `cloudwatch.getDashboard()` function just pulls that actual dashboard metric properties rather than their explicit values.

Do I need to define something more specific (ie: the actual aggregations or can I pull these dashboard metrics directly from a predefined dashboard)?

This is what I am currently finding:

```
{
  type: 'metric',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 6,
  height: 6,
  properties: {
    metrics: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ],
    view: 'bar',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    stat: 'XXX',
    period: XXX,
    title: 'XXX'
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want to find what the underlying dashboard is actually providing as the metric instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by invoking a metrics call and using a 95% percentile calculation.

```js
function p95(arr){
    // Creating the mean with Array.reduce
    let mean = arr.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
        return acc + curr;
    }, 0) / arr.length;
    
    // Assigning (value - mean) ^ 2 to every array item
    arr = arr.map((k)=>{
        return (k - mean) ** 2;
    });
    
    // Calculating the sum of updated array
    let sum = arr.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc + curr, 0);
    
    // Return 95th percentile
    return mean + (2 * Math.sqrt(sum / arr.length));
}
```

```js
async function get_average_lambda_execution_time(lambdaFunctionName) {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
    const startTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 14));
    const endTime = new Date();
    console.log(`Getting average lambda execution time for ${lambdaFunctionName} from ${startTime} to ${endTime}`);
    
    const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
    const params = {
        MetricName: 'Duration',
        Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
        Statistics: ['Average'],
        Period: 1440,
        StartTime: startTime,
        EndTime: endTime,
        Dimensions: [
            {
                Name: 'FunctionName',
                Value: lambdaFunctionName
            }
        ]
    };
    const metric = await cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(params).promise();
    const datapoints = metric.Datapoints;
    const durations = [];
    for (const datapoint of datapoints) {
        durations.push(datapoint.Average);
    }
    return p95(durations);
}
```

Comment: The question is about p99 while this attempt mentions p95. And the implementation of p95 is anything but the 95th percentile.